# GL.Lines Unity3D (C#) - Lines not rendered in edit view

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script attached to the main camera in my Unity scene that enables me to draw an isometric grid centered on the origin point, using good old OpenGl Lines.

As indicated in Unity's documentation ([there](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GL.html)), I launch the drawing on the "OnPostRender" event ; problem is lines only get drawn in Game view, and not in Edit view (even with the [ExecuteInEditMode] instruction).

Is there a way to get them drawn there?

--

Btw, here is the code (C#) for the function :

```
void OnPostRender()
{
    CreateLineMaterial();
    // set the current material
    lineMaterial.SetPass( 0 );

    GL.Begin( GL.LINES );

    GL.Color(mainColor);

    // Draw x lines
    for (int x = - gridSizeX / 2; x <= gridSizeX / 2; x++) {
        GL.Vertex3 (- gridSizeX / 4 + x, - gridSizeX / 8, 0 - x * 0.5f);
        GL.Vertex3 (gridSizeX / 4 + x, gridSizeX / 8, 0 - x * 0.5f);
    }
    // Draw y lines
    for (int y = - gridSizeY / 2; y <= gridSizeY / 2; y++) {
        GL.Vertex3 (- gridSizeY / 4 + y, gridSizeY / 8, 0 - y * 0.5f);
        GL.Vertex3 (gridSizeY / 4 + y, - gridSizeY / 8, 0 - y * 0.5f);
    }
    GL.End();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

God, I knew it would be like this. I got stuck on this the whole afternoon and when I eventually decide to submit a question here, I actually find the solution.

So I apologize for your wasted time.

Btw, solution was just to draw grid on the OnDrawGizmos event...